# Application of Theorem to solve $\nabla^2u=f$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

Does someone know where can I find an application (a solved exercise using this result) of this Theorem [image]

As you can see, the author of the book did not write a solved example of the theorem, and the only proposed exercises are those 3.

Or if you could post an example with respective solution using that Theorem ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is just a matter of picking a domain, a forcing and a boundary function and doing the integrals.

Comment: What exactly do you need? All you're doing is just plugigng in the given functions and do the integrals (if needed). There's not much more than that. If you want a proof, look up Green's equations.

Comment: [Here's an example that I did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803656/pde-ivp-delta-ux-y-e-x4-y4-u-yx-0-e-x-sinx/2808753#2808753) with specific functions and a specific domain.

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for the link Dylan:)

Comment: @Dylan This theorem only works if the equation has only one boundary condition right? If there are more boundary conditions, then this is not useful right?

Comment: No. It works if the entire boundary is defined. It doesn't matter how many smaller conditions there are. The example I linked happened to have only one boundary.

Comment: @Dylan hmm I don't understand. I can't imagine

Comment: Imagine if the boundary was a polygon, i.e a square or a triangle. You would need boundary conditions to be defined on all sides.

Comment: @Dylan ok so would be for instance a square, so $u=h_1$ on the lhs, $u=h_2$ on the rhs, and so on ?

Comment: But if that's the case, then how the double integral would be calculated if there is only one $h(x)$?

Comment: Who says $h$ has to be a function of $x$ only? That depends on the boundary. It can even be a function of both $h(x,y)$ if the boundary is some general curve.

Comment: @Dylan yes I know, $h$ could have n components, but my question is if it's posible to have  many $h_i$ ? (Like I wrote in the comment above)

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been saying. The boundary function can be broken up in many pieces, as long it defines the entire boundary.